# Is there a Targum Onkelos with Te'amim?

Tags: trop-cantillation

Is there a Targum Onkelos available online with Te'amim? I witnessed several versions of this in Yemenite and certain Sefardic books.

Comment: I'm surprised and didn't know that existed. I think the BIH said to do the 2 mikra 1 targum reading the mikra with teamim and targum plain without.

Comment: Some more standard versions put the אתנחתא in the Onkelos to show where to pause.

Comment: Doesn't the Venice Miqraot Gedolot have this? E.g. https://archive.org/details/The_Second_Rabbinic_Bible_Vol_1/page/n15/mode/1up?view=theater

Answer (score 9):

I found an old version [on HebrewBooks](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21711&st=&pgnum=1&hilite=). The print isn't very clear, though. [Here's](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21711&st=&pgnum=13) a sample page.

(Note: One side of the book has the actual Mikra, and the other side has the Targum.)

Comment: If anyone else is curious what they do in Vaychi, here's the page: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21711&st=&pgnum=171&hilite=

Comment: @Heshy Huh. Why?

Comment: Because Onkelos translates the brachos metaphorically and goes on for much longer than the text of the Chumash.